# Best practices for redux action creators

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

What is the best practice around redux action creator when it comes to calling action creators for 2 different events for a same functionality? Using redux-thunk to dispatch the actions.

E.g. Lets say I have to write an action creator for saving and printing the user name. Which action creator is better between the 2 below and why?

**Action Creator 1**

```
export function actionCreator1(actionType) 
{
     switch(actionType) 
     {
           case "save":
                // dispatch
           case "print": 
                // dispach
           default:
     }
}
```

**Action Creator 2**

```
export function actionCreatorSave() 
{
    // dispatch    
}
export function actionCreatorPrint() 
{
    // dispatch    
}
```

Comment: actionCreator2. Because it separates the two different actions altogether.

Comment: Down-voter- I would appreciate if you leave a comment for down-voting this question.

Answer (score -2):

Both are wrong. In redux, action creators don't dispatch actions. They return actions that you dispatch (in React this is preferably within react-redux mapDispatchToProps function).

http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/Actions.html#action-creators
mentions this as opposite to flux.

(the exception being async actions)

Comment: updated the question 'Using redux-thunk to dispatch the actions.'

Comment: OK, I was thinking on that example, but thought you were not using redux-thunk. Then both are OK, depending on use-case and preferences.

Comment: Thanks! Trying to figure out whats the consensus among the developer community regarding this

Comment: For exaple if you have some common logic for both actions you can put it above switch. In the second example you can duplicate or extract in a separate function and call from both action creators. If there is no common functionality than it is maybe cleaner to separate into two separate creators. But as I said both seem fine.